# How to add jupyterlab and notebook to Anaconda?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

i have created a new environment and i installed the jupyterlab server and notebook . But i can't find the jupyterlab widget on the Anaconda navigator home , i mean i can start the jupyterlab server with the conda prompt , but sometimes i accidentally close it and all my work is gone.
[Where i want to find the jupyterlab and notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Ndc.png)

in my `base` environment i can easily access to , because it has a shortcut on the menu home : here is an exemple :
[my base environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gapOr.png)

Answer (score 2):

Did you maybe install the "wrong" version of Jupyterlab or Jupyter Notebook?
I did, and when I uninstalled that version, reinstalled a new version, the widget showed up.

I installed the version 3.4.2 of JupyterLab and the widget didn't show up.
Then I uninstalled it from conda prompt with `conda uninstall jupyterlab`, then reinstalled a stable version with `conda install jupyterlab=3.3.2`. Now the widget shows up.